# Serverless lambda trigger read json file

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have lambda (Node) which has trigger to fire when a new JSON file added to our S3 bucket. Here is my lambda code

```js
module.exports.bookInfo = (event, context) => {
  console.log('Events ', JSON.stringify(event));
   event.Records.forEach((record) =>  {
      const filename = record.s3.object.key;
      const bucketname = record.s3.bucket.name;
      let logMsg = [];
      const s3File = `BucketName: [${bucketname}] FileName: [${filename}]`;
      console.log(s3File)
      logMsg.push(`Lambda execution started for ${s3File}, Trying to download file from S3`);
      try {
        s3.getObject({
          Bucket: bucketname,
          Key: filename
        }, function(err, data) {
          logMsg.push('Data is ', JSON.stringify(data.Body))
          if (err) {
                logMsg.push('Generate Error :', err);
                console.log(logMsg)
                return null;
              }          
          logMsg.push(`File downloaded successfully. Processing started for ${s3File}`);  
          logMsg.push('Data is ', JSON.stringify(data.Body))
          });
          } catch (e) {console.log(e)}
          });
          }
```

When i run this, i don't get file content and i suspect that lambda finishes execution before file read operation complete. I tried with async await without success. What i am missing here ? I was able to read small file of 1 kb but when my file grows like 100 MB, it causes issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suspect s3.getObject is an async call, so you will need to explicitly wait on the call

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it through async/await. Here is my code

```js
module.exports.bookInfo = (event, context) => {
  
   event.Records.forEach(async(record) =>  {
      const filename = record.s3.object.key;
      const bucketname = record.s3.bucket.name;
      const s3File = `BucketName: [${bucketname}] FileName: [${filename}]`;
      logMsg.push(`Lambda execution started for ${s3File}, Trying to download file from S3`);
      let response = await s3.getObject({
        Bucket: bucketname,
        Key: filename
      }).promise();
      })
      }
```